# Converting rasterstack to csv parallel processing in R

Tags: r, csv, parallel-processing, raster, r-raster

I have large rasters (>20 GB) and would like to convert each to csv file in a special format as follows:

```
unique_key_column
x_coordinate
y_coordinate
layer1_values
layer2_values
```

etc.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10,ncols=10)
r[] <- rnorm(10)
stack <- stack(r,r,r,r,r)

   #create function to convert coordinate to special format
   # -34.9 will be 1034900000 
   # sxxxdddddd, where s= sign (-=1, +=2), x=degrees (34=034), 
   # and d = decimal (.9=900000)

formatCoordinate <- function(x){
  first_part <- ifelse(x < 0 , "1","2")
  second_part <- abs(as.integer(x))
  #make sure 3 part has 6 decimal places, then convert it to string
  third_part <- substr(gsub(".+\\.","",as.character(format(round(x, 2),
                             nsmall = 6))),1,6)
  result <- sprintf("%s%03d%s",first_part,second_part,third_part)
  result
}

  #the actual processing

stack =readAll(stack)
names(stack) <-c("l1", "l2", "l3", "l4", "l5")
#convert rasterStack to dataframe
stackPoints <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(stack))
#format x and x coordinates
colX <- formatCoordinate(stackPoints$x)
colY <- formatCoordinate(stackPoints$y)
#combine formatted x and y coordinates to compose a unique key
pK <- paste0(colX, colY )
stackPoints["key"] <- pK
col_idx <- grep("key", names(stackPoints))
stackPoints <- stackPoints[, c(col_idx, (1:ncol(stackPoints))[-col_idx])]
#write results to a csv file
write.table(stackPoints, "r.csv", row.names=F, sep=";", dec=",", append=F)
```

The code above works for small rasters, but for large ones I couldn't load the stack to the RAM. 
is there a way to convert my code to use parallel processing? i.e. read the raster and write csv using multicore without the need to load the raster to the RAM (Mac OSX 10.11 and Ubuntu 14.04, each 8 cores ).
best,

Comment: what is your OS?  The parallel library you need to use depends on OS

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have Mac El-Captain and Ubuntu (on two different computers). I added this detail to the question :D

Comment: See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf) to get started.

Comment: If you're running out of memory using a single thread, increasing the number of threads is not necessarily going to help you.

Comment: The idea in the document is quite clear (application is difficult though! wished that there were some videos to explain the idea with more applications). I tried something like the function here [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/functions.pdf]. Unfortunately, I was not successful in applying the same function in the vignette on my function

Comment: You are right @C8H10N4O2, that is why the raster function of parallel processing seems like a good idea, as it read small pieces of data, process them, then write them to the output file, then repeat the process. The question is how? Three days trials with no luck

Comment: #the linke is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/functions.pdf

Answer (score 1):

First you want to figure out how to write a loop on a single thread, because moving from `for()` to `foreach()` will then be pretty straightforward.  I am not familiar with RasterStack object, but it looks like it has layers that are countable with `nlayers(x)` and extractable with `x[[i]]`.

So first I would write and debug something like:

```
for(i in 1:nlayers(stack)){
  #convert layer of rasterStack to dataframe
  layer_pts <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(stack[[i]]))

  #write layer_pts to a csv file
}
```

Then the `foreach()` is easy.  Just remember that you will need to start each thread with the `raster` package.  For faster merges I recommend `data.table`.

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
library(data.table)
registerDoMC(detectCores() - 2) # for me this is 40 - 2 = 38
layer_list <- 
  foreach(i = 1:nlayers(stack), .packages = c('raster', 'data.table') ) %dopar% {
    #convert layer of rasterStack to data.table
    layer_pts <- as.data.table(rasterToPoints(stack[[i]]))
    setkey(layer_pts, x, y) # data.table can key on x and y, no synthetic key needed
    layer_pts
  }

tbl_out <- Reduce(merge, layer_list) # uses keys from setkey

# if you wanted the "key" column (but not essential)
tbl_out[, key:= paste0( formatCoordinate(x), formatCoordinate(y) ) ]

write.csv(tbl_out, 'r.csv')
```

Note that if you are running out of memory you might have to reduce the number of cores used.  For example, `registerDoMC(4)` based on trial and error.

Comment: That is great! Now I know how to use foreach easily :D I tried it on my data and it works well and fast. But I am facing one problem though, one CSV is produced for one layer (total is about 450 CSV). Due to NA values, CSVs have different number of rows, hence I cannot easily join them together in one CSV per stack (even using the unique key. Is there a way around that? changing the loop to clip small tiles then convert them to CSVs (then add them together) could produce consistent number of columns, but it will take much longer and require more RAM and so

Comment: @user22364 OK your first sentence made me think you wanted one CSV per raster.  But now I see what you are looking for -- `layer1_values, layer2_values` etc. all on same line of CSV.  I will think about it.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much :D

Comment: @user22364 OK I think this is what you want.

Comment: sorry for getting back late to you, flue over the weekend is nothing good! i tried your updated code and R crashed even with 2 cores. I think the reason is the lack of memory, as one complete stack is about 30 GB.

Comment: @user22364 which step did it crash?  On `Reduce()`?  Please post description of error.

Comment: I tired it two more times, it crashes while exciting the loop, RStudio shows crash message and I can see that RAM is full . On a small subset, it works perfectly, but on the full stack it crashes.

Comment: @user22364 I think you have two choices.  1) You can partition each layer geographically so that you can write (append) points with all dimensions to csv without storing the whole `layer_list` in RAM at once.  This sounds like a pain.  2) You can get more RAM.  You can create an [EC2 instance with RStudio](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/) and upload your file to S3 bucket or direct to RStudio and run it from there.  You can get the m4.10xlarge which has 200GB and 40 cores.  (Just don't forget to turn it off when done).  Of course there is also 3) don't use R.

Comment: @C8H10V4O2 I will go with the first one :D pain but cheap!  I have indeed learned for you answer and appreciate the nice discussion, many thanks for that